# Removing unused CSS in Dynamic sites via node build tools

Tags: css, node.js, optimization

There is a way to remove unused css with **uncss** https://github.com/giakki/uncss

And an excellent blog post on the subject: http://addyosmani.com/blog/removing-unused-css/
However I fail to see how you would combine this approach dynamic content (for example generated by angular directives or async page loading) which will be missed by the uncss module.

Is there an optimal way to achieve this, I'm not wanting to manually go in and remove all the **bootstrap css** I'm not using.

Comment: Optimal way to achieve that is to sit and remove it by yourself, you cannot really rely on tools totally to get the job done

Comment: @Mr.Alien of course its always more perfect to do things manually but I want to automate the process.

Comment: You could put a FORCED checkpoint before the pages go online.        "Get the page > run uncss > publish" could be a possible workflow. Automating this will require some bit of additional scripting and inspection at least initially.

Answer (score 0):

My best recommendation would be to **create a couple of static pages with examples of all of the markup you anticipate needing**, and run uncss against that.

Even if the content is dynamic or asynchronously loaded, you should have a pretty good idea of what content is possible.

For example: you're probably very likely to need basic text formatting, headings, rich text content, lists, links, pictures, etc. Depending on the subject of your site, you'll also know whether you need to display code samples within `<code>`, `<kbd>` or `<pre>` tags.

However, it's not as likely that dynamic content would directly need to utilize the grid / layout system on its own, or would require any extraneous button styles.

**Build a test page that includes everything you anticipate using.** If you know there's something you want to keep, then throw it in. Otherwise feel confident knowing that uncss is doing it's job cleaning out everything else.